# Node Express Flash Messages Not Working

Tags: node.js, express

I don't know why express-messages is not working. I specified it in the app.js, specified it in the router/controller, and the view.

This is part of my app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');
app.use(flash());
app.use(require('connect-flash')());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);

  if(req.url == '/'){
    res.locals.isHome = true;
  }
  next();
});
```

This is my route where I specify the flash message:

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {failureRedirect: '/', failureFlash: 'Invalid username or password'}), function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log('Authentication Successful');
    req.flash('success', 'You are logged in');
    var usertype = req.user.type;
    res.redirect('/'+ usertype + 's/classes');
});

router.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.logout();
    req.flash('success', "You have logged out");
    res.redirect('/');
})
```

And this is my handlebar view where I have the messages tag:

```
<div class="col_12">
    <div class="col_9">
        {{{messages}}}
        {{#if errors}}
            {{#each errors}}
                <div class="notice error">
                    <i class="icon-remove-sign icon-large"></i>
                    {{msg}}
                    <a href="#close" class="icon-remove"></a>
                </div>
            {{/each}}
        {{/if}}
    {{{body}}}
```

Answer (score 5):

**connect-flash** saves the message into the session. You need use **express-session** before you add the `flash` middleware.

```
app.use(session());
app.use(flash())
```